# Unity app crashes on iPhone 6 ONLY?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine, xcode8

I have deployed a game made in Unity via TestFlight and do not know what to make of this issue - the game runs perfectly on all iPhone 6s and above. On iPhone 6 however and an iPad, it crashes right after the splash screen.

Crash report said initially it had to do with the Metal graphics settings - since (this is another problem) I haven't been able to get the crash reports from the last 2 builds, I am led to think it is still a graphics problem.

[image]

I've googled everything and found a few threads saying it was a Unity 5.5.0 problem and also that older devices do not support Metal. So today I updated to Unity 5.5.2f1 and removed Metal from the Graphics settings as 
various links have said this has been an issue - https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/crash-on-startup-5-5-0f1-ios-10.446813/

https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/ios-crash-on-presentrenderbuffer-gl-renderbuffer-in-presentgles-when-loading-a-scene-on-iphone-6s

but even with OpenGLES2 and 3 both in the options with Metal removed, it still crashes on just these older devices.

What is happening here? How can I fix this?

I am on the most updated Xcode, etc.

Comment: Did you try a clean build? Build it to a different directory. Another option is to select all your assets, right click and press export package. Save the package. Create a new project and import the package. Run it and see if the same issue happens.